# Slickgrid id column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid, dynamic-columns

Is there a way to bypass the necessity for an ID column?  My goal is to display 100,000+ results dynamically.  Currently, the only way I have found to do this is to create an "id" column on the table and then loop through it (which is quite costly).  If this is the case, is there a more efficient way of doing this? How can I hide the column when the grid is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the usage of a [dataview](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/slick.dataview.js) is causing the unique id requirement, then using a simple array as your data would suffice in removing the restriction.

If the advanced functionality of a dataview is required then you have the option of providing a field/property within the `setItems` call that will provide/override the `id` field (*the field must be present within each data object and have uniqueness across all the data elements*). If you cannot guarantee those two conditions, only two options are left.

- customize the source code of the dataview to provide a UUID during the processing of `updateIdxById`
- manually iterate the data and inject a UUID (*what you are currently doing*)

Regarding the column displaying:

Only those fields for which you have provided a column definition are rendered within the grid. Thus, as long as you don't provide the field in a column definition it will not be rendered. You can see in [this example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html) that each data object contains an `id` property but none of the elements of the `columns` array has a `field` that points to that property, as such it does not appear as a column.